# Best way to store non-sensitive data in android?

Tags: java, android, filesystems, local-storage

In my android app, I download a huge json string, and want to store it for offline use. Currently I am using shared preferences to store it. But I am thinking now it may not be the best way to store a large string.

Also the data doesn't have to be encrypted. It can be stored in plain text, so security is not a problem.

Does anyone know if there's a better way?

Answer (score 0):

[Store it as a file](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), using [Java file I/O](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/BasicIO), probably on [Android's internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: Why is using shared preferences a bad idea?

Comment: @omega: `SharedPreferences` is an XML file containing key/value pairs. The whole XML file is read in when you first use the `SharedPreferences`, meaning this "huge json string" will remain in memory, whether you like it or not, even after parsing it. You do not have lots of heap space on Android; wasting it on a second copy of the JSON data is not especially wise. Worse, if there are cases where your app wants to get to *other* preferences, but does not need the JSON, the JSON gets loaded into memory anyway. `SharedPreferences` is for small data; use other storage options for larger items.

Answer (score 0):

You have other options, such as:

Internal Storage, External Storage, SQLite database.

For more information check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences is a good option. It doesnt make any sense to store it in a file, SharedPreferences already does the same thing. I wouldnt suggest SQLite either because its just a string which still will be saved into a file. 
If the strings gets too big then i would suggest to have a method on splitting it into smaller objects then using SQLite for storing.